# Powershell commands written in python are not executing when python code is running as a window service

Tags: python, powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to execute powershell commands which interacts with MS Teams via python.
and further trying to execute the python code as a window service.
But powershell commands are not executing when i am running a code as a window service.
On command line the code works but not as a window service.
Can you please help me hereto work my code as a window service.

here is the python code :
import csv, subprocess

psxmlgen1=subprocess.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
'-ExecutionPolicy',
'Unrestricted',
'Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId XXXXX@XXXXX.com;Import-Csv -Path "test.csv" | foreach{Add-TeamUser -GroupId XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX -User $_.email} | ConvertTo-Json'], cwd=os.getcwd())
result = psxmlgen1.wait()

Answer (score 1):

you can call the code using below two methods.
import subprocess
subprocess.call('C:\myprogram.exe')

import os
os.startfile('C:\myprogram.exe') please find the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Kartheek, But this approach did not work for me. I want to login to ms teams using powershell commands in python  and this task i want to run as a window service.